# CTE recursive query in select statement

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL server version 8.0, one for local development and another on an Heroku Instance, more precisely on Heroku i'm using a service called [JAWSDB](https://www.jawsdb.com/).

For my project I have to use the following CTE query, because the structure of the table `tree_structure` is hierarchical.

The purpose of the query is that for every row in `tree_structure` I have to get all of its child, and then count how many user in `user_roles` table are present in that particular row and its child.

```
SELECT mtr.id,
       mtr.parent_id,
       mtr.name,
       mtr.manager_id,
       CONCAT(users.nome, ' ', users.cognome) as resp_name,
       (
           with recursive cte (id, name, parent_id) as (
               select id,
                      name,
                      parent_id
               from tree_structure as tr_rec
               where tr_rec.parent_id = mtr.id
                 and tr_rec.session_id = '2018'
               union all
               select tr.id,
                      tr.name,
                      tr.parent_id
               from tree_structure as tr
                        inner join cte
                                   on tr.parent_id = cte.id
               WHERE tr.session_id = '2018'
           )
           select count(distinct (user_id))
           from user_roles as ur_count
           where ur_count.structure_id in (select distinct(id) from cte)
       )                                  as utenti
FROM tree_structure as mtr
         LEFT JOIN users ON mtr.manager_id = users.id
WHERE level = 0
```

The problems is that on my local server it works whereas on the heroku instance it gaves me the following error:

`unknow columns mtr.id in where clause`.

Has someone any ideas of what is causing this error?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You have an ambiguous table reference in the CTE:

```
SELECT 
  ....   
    (with recursive cte (id, name, parent_id) as (
     ....
       from tree_structure as tr_rec        -- here you have aliased the table
      where tr_rec.id = tree_structure.id  -- here you refer to the table and its alias
        and tr_rec.session_id = '2018'
      union all
      ....
    )
    ....
 ) as utenti
....
```

Table tree_structure is used in the subselect and in the outermost select. The good practice is to make an unique alias for every table reference you have used.

Also you have a typo in the condition that should check self-referencing of the hierarcy root node:

```
where tr_rec.id = tr_rec.parent_id
  and tr_rec.session_id = '2018'
```

Comment: I've updated the query adding an alias also to the outer tree_structure table, but it's not working giving the same error: `unknown column mtr.id in where clause`. About the typo, if I understand what you mean, I think you aren't right, because that check means: "Start search recursively all the children of this row (represented by mtr.id)" and also the condition `tr_rec.id = tr_rec.parent_id` is always false, because a child is never his own parent.

Comment: This is the scope problem. You should use `where tr_rec.parent_id = tr_rec.id` instead of `where tr_rec.parent_id = mtr.id`

Comment: There is two approaches how to distinguish the root node from all the other nodes. Fisrt is to set its parent to the NULL. Another is to set its parent to itself. In your case `where tr_rec.parent_id = tr_rec.id` means `the root node for hierarcy having session_id=2018`

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm using the first one, so when I reach a root node it's `parent_id` column is set to `NULL`. But what I'm asking is not if my query is right, because as I said before, my query in local environment **works** whereas in my production environment **not**, this is the strange thing. And in addition if i use your control (`where tr_rec.parent_id = tr_rec.id`) I'm not able to count users anymore. I hope I understood correctly what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

OK guys I found out why the query was wrong. Apparently since MySQL version 8.0.14 they introduced support for using external parameters within subqueries.

My local version was 8.0.16 but the online version was 8.0.11 so because of this my query didn't work.